# I cannot connect to Microsoft Access using Dev C++

Tags: c++, ms-access, dev-c++

This is my code to connect to MS Access but it's not working, and I also can't find where to put the file address. Can someone help fix my code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    HENV hEnv = NULL;
    // Env Handle from SQLAllocEnv()
    HDBC hDBC = NULL;
    // Connection handle
    HSTMT hStmt = NULL;
    // Statement handle
    UCHAR szDSN[SQL_MAX_DSN_LENGTH] = "mpj8";
    // Data Source Name buffer
    UCHAR* szUID = NULL;
    // User ID buffer
    UCHAR* szPasswd = NULL;
    // Password buffer
    UCHAR szModel[128]; 
    // Model buffer 
    SDWORD cbModel; 
    // Model buffer bytes recieved 
    UCHAR szSqlStr[250]= "Select * From bank"; 
    // SQL string 
    RETCODE retcode; 
    // Return code
    // Allocate memory for ODBC Environment handle  
    SQLAllocEnv (&hEnv);
    // Allocate memory for the connection handle
    SQLAllocConnect (hEnv, &hDBC);
    // Connect to the data source "db97" using userid and password.
    retcode = SQLConnect (hDBC, szDSN, SQL_NTS, szUID, SQL_NTS, szPasswd, SQL_NTS); 

    if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        // Allocate memory for the statement handle
        retcode = SQLAllocStmt (hDBC, &hStmt);
        // Prepare the SQL statement by assigning it to the statement handle
        retcode = SQLPrepare (hStmt, szSqlStr, sizeof (szSqlStr));
        // Execute the SQL statement handle
        retcode = SQLExecute (hStmt);
        // Project only column 1 which is the models
        SQLBindCol (hStmt, 1, SQL_C_CHAR, szModel, sizeof(szModel), &cbModel);
        // Get row of data from the result set defined above in the statement
        retcode = SQLFetch (hStmt);

        while (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) { 
            printf(\t%s\n,szModel); 
            // Print row (model) 
            retcode = SQLFetch (hStmt);
            // Fetch next row from result set
        }

        // Free the allocated statement handle
        SQLFreeStmt (hStmt, SQL_DROP);
        // Disconnect from datasource
        SQLDisconnect (hDBC);
    }

    // Free the allocated connection handle
    SQLFreeConnect (hDBC);
    // Free the allocated ODBC environment handle     
    SQLFreeEnv (hEnv);

    return 0;
```

Comment: Please consider adding to your question detail about any error messages you are getting, and/or a more-detailed description of what exactly isn't working. Thank you.

Comment: stdafx.cpp
1>  nb.cpp
1>c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\nb\nb\nb.cpp(230): error C2664: 'SQLConnectW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'UCHAR [32]' to 'SQLWCHAR *'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Comment: 1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\nb\nb\nb.cpp(237): error C2664: 'SQLPrepareW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'UCHAR [250]' to 'SQLWCHAR *'
1

Comment: >          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\nb\nb\nb.cpp(252): error C2017: illegal escape sequence
1>c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\nb\nb\nb.cpp(252): error C2065: 't' : undeclared identifier

Comment: 1>c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\nb\nb\nb.cpp(252): error C2017: illegal escape sequence
1>c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\nb\nb\nb.cpp(252): error C2065: 's' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\nb\nb\nb.cpp(252): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'n'
1>c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\nb\nb\nb.cpp(252): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\nb\nb\nb.cpp

Comment: (281): fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at 'c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\nb\nb\nb.cpp(198)' was matched

Comment: These are the errors messages that I am getting. Also, I can't add the file that I need to copy data from.

Comment: Those are compiler errors. If your program doesn't even compile, your problem can't have anything to do with connecting to MSAccess - it wasn't able to run, let alone try to connect. You should state your question more clearly: it's about how to use the API properly and the language syntax, not about problems connecting. Also put the errors in your question, correctly formatted, that'll make life easier for whoever tries to help.

Comment: @user1248092 Not sure if it is causing your problems, but I would advise against using DevC++. Use one of the good [alternatives listed here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dev-c%2b%2b/info) instead. Given that you want to use MS Acess, the Express edition of Visual Studio might be a good choice.

Comment: The other problem is that Express version does not contain the Data tab. That's why I went to Dev C++